# How do I set a parameterized type of a variable to the type of class the variable is in?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am making a Discord bot with several 'command features'

```
public class MyBotCommandFeature extends MyBotFeature {
    @NotNull public final Set<MyBotCommand> commands;

    public MyBotCommandFeature(@NotNull MyBotCommand @NotNull ... commands) {
        if (commands.length == 0) {
            this.commands = new HashSet<>();
        } else {
            this.commands = stream(commands).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @CheckForNull
    @CheckReturnValue
    public Set<MyBotCommand> getExtraCommands(@NotNull Guild guild) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Each feature has several commands (MyBotCommand). MyBotCommand has two abstract methods for handling text commands (runTextCommand) and slash commands (runSlashCommand).

Because some commands will want to refer to the `MyBotFeature` they're a part of, `MyBotCommandFeature` is currently one of the parameters of these abstract methods. However, to use any feature-specific features, commands currently have to cast `MyBotCommandFeature` to, say, `ExampleCommandFeature`.

```
public abstract class MyBotCommand {
    public abstract void runTextCommand(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event, @NotNull MyBotCommandFeature feature);
    public abstract void runSlashCommand(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event, @NotNull MyBotCommandFeature feature);
}
```

```
public final class ExampleFeature extends MyBotCommandFeature {
    public ExampleFeature() {
        super(new MyBotCommand() {
            @Override
            public void runTextCommand(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event, @NotNull MyBotCommandFeature feature) {
                final ExampleFeature self = ((ExampleFeature) feature);
                // Use self to respond to the text command
            }

            @Override
            public void runSlashCommand(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event, @NotNull MyBotCommandFeature feature) {
                final ExampleFeature self = ((ExampleFeature) feature);
                // Use self to respond to the slash command
            }
        });
    }
```

I was hoping I'd be able to make `MyBotCommand` be parameterized with the generic type `<F extends MyBotCommandFeature>`. Then instead of the abstract functions taking `MyBotCommandFeature` as parameters, they'd take `F`.

```
public abstract class MyBotCommand<F extends MyBotCommandFeature> {
    public abstract void runTextCommand(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event, @NotNull F feature);
    public abstract void runSlashCommand(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event, @NotNull F feature);
}
```

However, I'm not sure I would then declare the type of the set of commands (defined in `MyBotCommandFeature`, not individually in each feature) to say that the generic type F is the same as the class the set of commands is being stored in. I would want to be able to do something like this.

```
public class MyBotCommandFeature extends MyBotFeature {
    @NotNull public final Set<MyBotCommand<this>> commands;

    public MyBotCommandFeature(@NotNull MyBotCommand<this> @NotNull ... commands) {
        if (commands.length == 0) {
            this.commands = new HashSet<>();
        } else {
            this.commands = stream(commands).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @CheckForNull
    @CheckReturnValue
    public Set<MyBotCommand<this>> getExtraCommands(@NotNull Guild guild) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public final class ExampleFeature extends MyBotCommandFeature {
    public ExampleFeature() {
        super(new MyBotCommand<ExampleFeature>() {
            @Override
            public void runTextCommand(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event, @NotNull ExampleFeature feature) {
                // Use feature to respond to the text command
            }

            @Override
            public void runSlashCommand(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event, @NotNull ExampleFeature feature) {
                // Use feature to respond to the text command
            }
        });
    }
```

I have tried using a wildcard '?' instead of 'this' but then I'm stuck on what to pass to the abstract methods after matching a JDA event to a MyBotCommand. For example, I have this for slash commands, but I am unable to pass MyBotCommandFeature to MyBotCommand::runSlashCommand even though the MyBotCommand instance is made in the MyBotCommandFeature I am passing.

```
    @Override
    public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
        for (MyBotCommandFeature feature : features) {
            for (MyBotCommand<?> command : feature.commands) {
                if (command.name.equals(event.getName())) {
                    command.runSlashCommand(event,feature);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there some way I can do something like this? If not, is there an alternative way to avoid having to cast `MyBotCommandFeature` to an individual feature in most of my `MyBotCommand` implementations?

Comment: Is there a reason why `MyBotCommand<?>` won't work in `MyBotCommandFeature`? At least from what you've shown, I believe the answer is no.

Comment: @Michael Hm, that seems to mostly work, but then I'm stuck on what to pass to the abstract methods when I iterate through the set. I'll append an example to the original question

Comment: So how's the responsible of handling the commands? the Feature? Where's the output expected to be delivered?

Comment: MyBotCommand::runTextCommand and MyBotCommand::runSlashCommand are done in a separate class called MyBotCommandHandler and the output is delivered to Discord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? There is a type variable on `MyBotCommandFeature` indicating the type argument of the `MyBotCommand` that its commands are. Then the subclass `ExampleFeature` can extend `MyBotCommandFeature` with itself as the type argument. Of course, someone could write a class `FeatureA extends MyBotCommandFeature<FeatureB>`, but everything is still type-safe and should compile without any warnings or casts, at least with what you've shown so far.

```
public abstract class MyBotCommand<F> {
    public abstract void runTextCommand(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event, @NotNull F feature);
    public abstract void runSlashCommand(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event, @NotNull F feature);
}

public class MyBotCommandFeature<F> extends MyBotFeature {
    @NotNull public final Set<MyBotCommand<F>> commands;

    public MyBotCommandFeature(@NotNull MyBotCommand<F> @NotNull ... commands) {
        if (commands.length == 0) {
            this.commands = new HashSet<>();
        } else {
            this.commands = stream(commands).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @CheckForNull
    @CheckReturnValue
    public Set<MyBotCommand<F>> getExtraCommands(@NotNull Guild guild) {
        return null;
    }
}

public final class ExampleFeature extends MyBotCommandFeature<ExampleFeature> {
    public ExampleFeature() {
        super(new MyBotCommand<ExampleFeature>() {
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```